# support of addition of function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\phi_j:X\to \Bbb{R}$ be collection of smooth function $\phi_i\ge 0$ which support are locally finite.

Given function $\rho(x) = \sum\phi_j$ which is again well defined and smooth due to locally finite.

There is a relation between support that  I can't work it out.

$$\text{supp}(\rho) = \overline{\bigcup\text{supp}(\phi_i)}$$

I know in general $\text{supp}(f+g) \subset \text{supp}(g) \bigcup\text{supp}(f)$ why they are equal even for closure here?

Comment: what is the "locally finite support"?

Comment: @Leon a collection of set is locally finite means given any $x\in X$ has a neiborhood intersect finite many set,for here take collection of set as $\text{supp}(\phi_i)$

Comment: Maybe I get the point ,the key point to make the equality hold is $\phi_i \ge 0$ since then if $\rho = 0$ then all the element are automatically zero,for function with signed,there may be some cancellation to make the inclusion strict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s(f) = \{x \in X \mid f(x) \ne 0\}$. Then $\operatorname{supp}(f)  = \overline{s(f)}$.

Since all $\phi_j \ge 0$, we have $\rho \ge \phi_i \ge 0$ for all $i$ and
$$s(\phi_i) = \{x \in X \mid \phi_i(x) > 0\} \tag{1} ,$$
$$s(\rho) = \{x \in X \mid \rho(x) > 0\} \tag{2} ,$$
$$s(\phi_i) \subset s(\rho) \tag{3} ,$$
$$\bigcup s(\phi_i) = s(\rho)  \tag{4} .$$
$(3)$ implies $\operatorname{supp}(\phi_i) \subset \operatorname{supp}(\rho)$ and we get
$$\overline{\bigcup s(\phi_i)} \subset \overline{\bigcup\operatorname{supp}(\phi_i)} \subset \operatorname{supp}(\rho) \tag{5} .$$
Now let $x \in \operatorname{supp}(\rho)$ and $U$ be an open neigborhood of $x$. There exists $x_U \in U \cap s(\rho)$. By $(4)$ we have $x_U \in \bigcup s(\phi_i)$. Thus $x \in \overline{\bigcup s(\phi_i)}$ and therefore
$$\overline{\bigcup s(\phi_i)} = \overline{\bigcup\operatorname{supp}(\phi_i)} = \operatorname{supp}(\rho) \tag{6} .$$
This is true without any assumptions on the family $\{ \operatorname{supp}(\phi_i) \}$.

Comment: thanks , In fact this arguement can be devide into two part,first we can show $\text{supp}(\rho) = \overline{\bigcup\text{supp}(\phi_i)}$ second we know arbitary union of closed locally finite sets are closed hence we can remove the closure

Comment: @yili Correct, I modified my answer to make this transparent.